# Nesting IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, vlookup

If the value in cell A1 is found in column B, then populate with the text `321` unless the value in cell A1 is found in column C, in which case populate with the text `121` instead. If the contents of cell A1 are not in either columns B or C, then populate with `0` or `No`.

This is half of the statement (unable to nest successfully with the other half of the statement):

> =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$1000,0)),"","321")

Comment: This is how you'll nest it. `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$1000,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$1000,0)),0,121),321)`. But pnuts formula should work just fine.

Comment: thanks. much appreciated. worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,0)=A1,321),IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1,0)=A1,121),0))
```